# Automatizar etiquetas de proteccion de Microsotf azure para enviar emails con python

Tags: python, email, outlook

Tengo una rutina con Python que envía emails a ciertos usuarios de manera automática, se ha integrado una etiqueta de protección de microsoft azure obligatoria.

¿Hay alguna manera de automatizar esta etiqueta de protección para que se marque sola como confidencial?

```
def envio_mail_prueba(mail, id):
    print(mail)
    print(id)
    #Creo un objeto de outlook
    outlook = win32.Dispatch('Outlook.Application')

    #Creo un objeto de mensaje
    mensaje = outlook.CreateItem(0)
    mensaje.Subject = 'Correo de prueba'
    mensaje.To = mail
    mensaje.Body ="Aquí vendría el cuerpo del mensaje" 
                  

    mensaje.Display()
    mensaje.Send()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes hacerlo con el atributo Sensitivity:

```
def envio_mail_prueba(mail, id):
    print(mail)
    print(id)
    #Creo un objeto de outlook
    outlook = win32.Dispatch('Outlook.Application')

    #Creo un objeto de mensaje
    mensaje = outlook.CreateItem(0)
    mensaje.Subject = 'Correo de prueba'
    mensaje.To = mail

    mensaje.Sensitivity = 3 # ESTE ES EL CAMPO

    mensaje.Body ="Aquí vendría el cuerpo del mensaje"           
    mensaje.Display()
    mensaje.Send()
```

Comment: Saludos, gracias por el aporte, tu respuesta quedaria mucho mejor si agregas links de documentación y una breve explicación de cómo tu respuesta soluciona el problema de OP. ;)